How many of the tetracubes can be used to make a 2x4x4 cuboid?
Beginner puzzle
This puzzle is intended to be suitable for people who are new to puzzle solving.
Clarification: Both experienced solvers and new solvers are welcome to post solutions to this puzzle.

Each of the shapes shown has been made from four unit cubes. For each shape, Max takes eight copies of the shape and tries to fit them together to make a 2x4x4 cuboid.

How many of the shapes can be used to make a cuboid of this size in this way?

Attribution: UK Junior Mathematical Challenge 2021


 All of them


 For the L, two copies can make a 1×2×4. Then 4 copies can make a 2×4×4.


 For the T, four copies can make a 1×4×4. Then 2 copies can make a 2×4×4.


 For the bottom left shape, two copies can make a 2×2×2. Then 4 copies can make a 2×4×4.


 For the bottom right shape, two copies can make a 2×2×2. Then 4 copies can make a 2×4×4.

